# Only run javascript on specific page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've been wondering how to do this for a while. What I do in my CSS is quite easy. I use unique ids, or classes to make sure the CSS code I have is ran at the right place and can obviously still be in the asset pipeline. However I'm not sure how to achieve this with javascript.

I have a chunk of javascript that I'd like to run on only a specific page. Which is:

```
rooms/show.html.erb
```

now my rooms.coffee

```
apiKey    = undefined
sessionId = undefined
token     = undefined
session   = undefined

getApiAndToken = ->
  apiKey    = gon.api_key if gon
  sessionId = gon.session_id if gon
  token     = gon.token if gon
  initializeSession()
  return

initializeSession = ->
 .....
```

goes like this, what's the standard way to only run this  javascript on a specific page?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to add it directly to your show page.

If you want to be more fancy create a JavaScript file in your assets, exclude it from asset pipeline and then include it with JavaScript include tab.